# Tree structure, unique names/parent, Entity Framework transactions or locking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database

My apologies if this has been asked before...

I have some EF model classes like this:

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    [Column("folder_id")]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("organization_id")]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [MaxLength(MAX_NAME_LENGTH)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("parent_folder_id")]
    public int? ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentFolderId")]
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [Key]
    [Column("file_id")]
    public int FileId { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("folder_id")]
    [Required]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }

}
```

I am working on several operations to these two tables. I would like to run a read, do some checks, and then write back. My concern is concurrency though. For instance:

1. A request to create File "Samuel" in Folder "Jamison" is received

   - Check to see there is no File or Folder named "Samuel" in "Jamison"
   - Create File "Samuel" in Folder "Jamison"
2. A request to create Folder "Samuel" in Folder "Jamison" is received

   - Check to see there is no File or Folder named "Samuel" in "Jamison"
   - Create Folder "Samuel" in Folder "Jamison"

The checks are done in the app, so how can I ensure that the checks don't both succeed and result in a successful create operation?

My first thought was transactions, but I feel like I need to change the isolation level or do some pessimistic locking. Or maybe a different approach? How would you guys approach this problem in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested concurrency handling for EF is Optimistic Concurrency.
Basically, you need to add a Timestamp column to your models and specify this column to be the concurrency handling:

```
[Timestamp]
public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

This will instruct to EF to check if the current value of your entities timestamp matches the version in the database; if it does the operation will succeed in otherwise a DbUpdateConcurrencyException will be thrown and you can catch it to show error messages to the user.

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for more details.

How to use this approach, every time you add a file or a subfolder modify the UpdatedDate value of the Parent (This will ensure that only one operation will pass).

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I feel this ensures that I don't overwrite an updated row. The problem here is that I need to ensure that different rows are maintaining integrity between each other. In other words I need to ensure that when I update a row that no other row with the same ParentFolderId has the same name, etc. EDIT: Although, maybe I'm just not understanding how your answer can be used to solve my issue?

Comment: Thinking about this more, I suppose I could queue up a bunch of operations. I do my check, I update the date on the ParentFolder, and then save. My assumption is if there is a concurrency exception NONE of the edits will go through. Then I just need to update the date on every operation that modifies something inside the parent. In that way I ensure no two operations occur against the same parent without an exception being thrown. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Add-on question, Is there someway to update only the Timestamp field? I'm using the byte[] array as specified in that link you showed instead of DateTimeOffset. I'm not modifying anything about the parent row, I'm using it more like a synchronization construct.

Comment: Yes, you are in the right track.when you modified the date only the first Update will succeed, the second update will not match the Parent Timestamp and will fail. In this case, I suggest a DateTimeOffset to easily update the field in the code. Timestamp can be updated as well but at the end you end up having less semantics.